# How to customize survey builder form by programatically in drupal

Tags: views, 7, forms, webforms

I have installed [survey builder](https://www.drupal.org/project/survey_builder) module. Using this we created survey pages, but form elements are not aligned properly. I want to give some style to survey form elements.

How can i make it is possible? can any one suggest any idea for this ?